# The remote procedure call failed and did not execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BF)

Tags: com, windows-server-2008, adsi

I did ask this question at Microsoft forums but did not get any reply. I am asking here hoping to get an answer. My query is detailed below.

I have a C# application which manages user's on AD using ADSI APIs. For managing user's password, I make use of IADsUser.SetPassword(string NewPassword) of Interop.ActiveDs.dll.

The issue I am facing is only when domain controller is installed on Windows 2008 enterprise SP2 OS. It is not reproducible on Windows 2008 R2.

When I try setting the password one user by one, there is no issue at all. But if I create threads for each user and then each thread calls this API I  get **"The remote procedure call failed and did not execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BF)**" .

Apart from this, I do not see anything on the event viewer on the DC or anywhere. This something similar to what is mentioned here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960007 which is for 2003, has someone seen this issue on 2008 enterprise SP2 ? Is this a known issue ?

I am installing all the updates which are pending using windows updates, hopefully it might resolve. Can someone please answer if they have seen this issue and what were the steps taken?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something similar running an ASP.NET web application in VS 2015, AND I also had a LightSwitch application running in VS 2012 *under different credentials*.  Rebooting did not do the trick.  Enabling native code debugging did:

[Debugging unmanaged code while debugging managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519603/debugging-unmanaged-code-while-debugging-managed-code)

I did not do anything except turn it on.  My app ran fine after that.  I went ahead and turned it off and it still ran fine.  Whatever works.