# AccessViolationException - When calling Botan::LibraryInitializer

Tags: c#, c++-cli, botan

I'm building a managed wrapper for Botan crypto in .NET and following the getting started instructions here

[Getting Started](http://botan.randombit.net/manual/firststep.html)

And the [library reference](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1LibraryInitializer.html)

I'm trying to execute the LibraryInitializer first, but when I call it it throws an AccessViolationException - inside my INIT() method.

My code it like this.

**C# test program**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using BotanCrypto_ManagedWrapper;
using System.Numerics;

namespace TestBotanWrapper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BotanCrypto BC = new BotanCrypto();
            BC.INIT();


            UInt64 num = 100;

            BigInteger b = BC.Test(num);


            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Wrapper CPP**

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "BotanCrypto_ManagedWrapper.h"
using namespace BotanCrypto_ManagedWrapper;

void BotanCrypto::INIT(){
    LibraryInitializer init;

}

BigInteger BotanCrypto::Test(UInt64 x){
    //try{
        BigInt n = 1000000;
        x = 2;
    //}catch(SystemException^ ex){

    //  x = 0;
    //}
    return x;
}
```

**Wrapper Header**

```
// BotanCrypto_ManagedWrapper.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace Numerics;
using namespace Botan;

namespace BotanCrypto_ManagedWrapper {

    public ref class BotanCrypto
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    public:
        BigInteger Test(UInt64 k);
        void INIT();
    };


}
```

I don't even know if I'm calling the libraryinitializer correctly.  I'm not too familiar with C++.  Any help is appreciated. thanks.

EDIT I tried the same thing in a Win32 Console application but get the same result

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <botan/botan.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   try
      {
      Botan::LibraryInitializer init;

      // ...
      }
   catch(std::exception& e)
      {
      //std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
      }
    return 0;
}
```

**Unhandled exception at 0x0F12422E (botan.dll) in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003B0000.**

Comment: I would get this under [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and see what is loaded (or supposed ot be loaded) at `0x003B0000`. If its in your DLL, then you should be able to get a symbol. I think your other option is to enable native code debugging under Visual Studio. For that, see [How to: Enable Debugging of Unmanaged Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Debugging unmanaged code while debugging managed code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2519603).

Comment: One isse - That page mentions that the `LibraryInitializer` lifetime must exceed that of all other Botan objects.  That means you should create a class constructor for your BotanCrypto class, and put the `LibraryInitializer init` in there.  Your code is simply creating and destroying by tucking it in that INIT function.

Answer (score 0):

I would change:

```
LibraryInitializer init;
```

to:

```
try
{
   LibraryInitializer init;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

As outlined under pitfalls in the getting started page.