# Unable to debug native code from managed despite enabling native code debugging

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, mixed-mode

I have a managed project (.net 4.6.2) which calls into a native dll. If I put a breakpoint in the native code, it hits it, but if I try to inspect stack variables I get a rather annoying

> Inspection of unmanaged type 'MyTypeInHere*' requires unmanaged
>   debugging to be enabled.  Please set the debugger type to 'Mixed' and
>   try again

I followed steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019, [Debugging unmanaged code while debugging managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519603/debugging-unmanaged-code-while-debugging-managed-code) but I still cannot inspect types.

In the managed project properties, under debug I've enabled `enable native code debugging` and under the build page I've checked `allow unsafe code`. Further in launchSettings.json, I have `"nativeDebugging": true`

Also note that in the native project property settings I've set the Debugger type to `mixed`.

Does anybody know what's preventing me debugging native code?

Thanks

Comment: When the breakpoint works then you can be sure that you configured the debugger correctly.  You have to be a bit careful about clicking in the Stack Trace window, it lets you jump to a managed method.  That switches the debugger engine, it now doesn't know anything about unmanaged code anymore.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know what's preventing me debugging native code?

It is quite strange and I followed the sample which your link provided and it works well. In fact, all the steps are just the rule.

So please check these:

**1)** Please make sure that your c++ project is using **Active(Debug)** Configuration and **x64** platform. When you change `Debugger type` to `mixed` and then click Apply, please remember to rebuild the project.

**2)** when you reference the native code into C# project, please close the VS Instance, delete **obj**,**bin**,`.vs` hidden folder and then reopen your c# project. After that, please make sure that you check `Enable Native Code debugging`, then rebuild the entire solution.

**3)** Add breakpoints where you want to break and begin stepping through the code. Make sure your have placed your breakpoints in code which the C# application calls into.

**4)** change the `target gramework` to `4.7.2` to test again.

**5)** Please try to create a new `net framework 4.7.2` c# project to test whether the issue is caused by the old project.

**In addition**, if all the steps does not work, please [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: the solution I'm working on is pretty big, but I did steps 1-4 and i still cannot inspect native variables. i'll try to try 5 tomorrow... if it does or doesn't work, what does that mean?
note breakpoints are hit in both managed and native code (that was never the problem).
I really don't want to do a repair.